# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras' , I tried almost everything

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

[packages1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVZL2.png)

[packages2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U41rY.png)

These are my packages on anaconda . I get this error on last photo . I tried almost everything on stackoverflow and on github .I tried every way to import keras and tensorflow . I downgraded tensorflow,keras but i got any other errors like numpy is not compatible etc. I downgraded numpy to but this time keras required higher version . I spend my last 1 week with this error . So i need help , We can meet on discord,zoom with someone who wants to help. Thank you .

from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
/ from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

these are my lines to try import . I tried these like python.keras , tensorflow.keras , tensorflow.python.keras none of them worked .

```
import keras
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [6] in <cell line: 1>
    import keras

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py:3 in <module>
    from . import utils

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py:26 in <module>
    from .vis_utils import model_to_dot

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py:7 in <module>
    from ..models import Model

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py:12 in <module>
    from .engine.training import Model

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\__init__.py:7 in <module>
    from .network import get_source_inputs

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py:15 in <module>
    from . import saving

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py:21 in <module>
    from .. import optimizers

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\__init__.py:1 in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'
```

Comment: Have you tried just running `import tensorflow` before that? I have a hunch it's not finding the base package name because you run `from tensorflow import keras`. Just a hunch though

Comment: Also, instead of screenshots please use the code tool to put the raw error text into the question. It helps a lot with understanding what you're trying to ask here

Comment: I never imported tensorflow . Also for to make another try I restarted anaconda and i write just "import keras " as a first line . Runned only this line and it says Using Tensorflow backend Traceback (most recent call last): ...... ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'

Comment: i added the code

Comment: Have you installed the packages into their own Conda environment?  If so, have you activated that environment and pointed your IDE to the correct Python interpreter?

Comment: I just did it all over to try again . New enviroment created , activate env , install tensorflow,numpy,nltk and install spyder . Go spyder -> import tensorflow.keras as keras . Get same error above .

Comment: I checked packages with conda list and keras 2.4.3 , tensorflow 2.3.0 succesfully installed .

Answer (score 1):

You should import Keras from Tensorflow, like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
```

And to import the modules you want from Keras, you can use

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, TimeDistributed, Dropout
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
```

Comment: I just 1 minute ago created new enviroment and installed tensorflow , numpy , spyder . I wrote this codes which you said and get same error . First I run" import tensorflow as tf" , it works no error . But second line "import tensorflow.keras as keras" didnt work .